# Radio button style using icon buttons in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I want to create a radio button style voting system using icons in Flutter (Dart) which looks like this:
[vote icons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G5xuf.png)

The concept is simple:
The page will display a movie, the user can then vote on that movie using the Icon buttons above.
When a vote is made, the icon changes to red and the movie is added to an array.

The tricky part which I am struggling with is:

1. Changing the color of the icon after selected
2. Making sure that the other icons remain black
3. Changing the other icons back to black if the user selects a different choice

Thanks in advance!

Comment: share your code. I will be happy to help you.

Comment: thank you Ujjwal, really appreciate the offer! Seems like Martin posted an answer already to my problem which has worked so this has been resolved. thanks again

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image: Result]

```dart
class Example extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ExampleState createState() => _ExampleState();
}

class _ExampleState extends State<Example> {
  int _selected = null;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: [
        _icon(0, text: "No way", icon: Icons.face),
        _icon(1, text: "Maybe", icon: Icons.local_movies),
        _icon(2, text: "Looks good", icon: Icons.local_pizza),
        _icon(3, text: "Can't wait", icon: Icons.local_fire_department),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget _icon(int index, {String text, IconData icon}) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
      child: InkResponse(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            Icon(
              icon,
              color: _selected == index ? Colors.red : null,
            ),
            Text(text, style: TextStyle(color: _selected == index ? Colors.red : null)),
          ],
        ),
        onTap: () => setState(
          () {
            _selected = index;
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: amazing thank you! and for the quick response too!

Answer (score 0):

```
GestureDetector(
            onTap:() {},
            child: Card(
                elevation: 1,
                child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                        horizontal: 15.w,
                        vertical: 10,
                    ),
                    child: Column(
                        children: [
                            Icon(
                                Icons.ac_unit_outlined,
                                size: 40,
                                color: _valgroup == 1
                                ? Colors.orange
                                : Colors.blue,
                            ),
                            Radio(
                                activeColor: Colors. orange,
                                groupValue: _valgroup,
                                value: 1,
                                onChanged: (int? value) {
                                    if (value != null) {
                                        setState(() {
                                            _valgroup = value;
                                        });
                                    }
                                },
                            ),
                        ],
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
```

Comment: color: _valgroup == 1 ? Colors.orange : Colors.blue, this will help us